# jQuery - Get ID from one object, run AJAX call, get next ID, repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select list that is populated with ID's from a database. How can I have jQuery take each of those ID's, one by one, then run an AJAX function and append those results after the corresponding object?

I know how to make the AJAX call and do the append after the object, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to get one ID, run the AJAX call, and once that's done move on to the next ID, and repeat until there is no more left.

Here's a sample of my HTML:

```html
<select id="thingsList">
    <optgroup label="Name1">
     <option id="thing1" class="thingsListID" value="1" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name2">
     <option id="thing2" class="thingsListID" value="2" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name3">
     <option id="thing3" class="thingsListID" value="3" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name4">
     <option id="thing4" class="thingsListID" value="4" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: you can iterate through $("optgroup option").each(function(k,v){})

Comment: `each` falls apart when dealing with async code.  It will fire off all requests at once.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the loadData to do a ajax request and return your html fragment

```js
function loadData(item, callback) {
  
  var html = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < (Math.random() * 1000) % 15; i++)
    html += "<option>" + (new Date()).toString() + "</option>"; // just for example
  // call you ajax here
  callback(html);
};

$("button").click(function () {
  $("#thingsList").find("optgroup").each(function (i, group) {
    var item = $(group).find("option:first");
    $(group).find("option").not(item).remove(); // if you need to erase and add again
    loadData(item, function (html) {
      $(html).insertAfter(item);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="thingsList">
    <optgroup label="Name1">
     <option id="thing1" class="thingsListID" value="1" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name2">
     <option id="thing2" class="thingsListID" value="2" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name3">
     <option id="thing3" class="thingsListID" value="3" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Name4">
     <option id="thing4" class="thingsListID" value="4" disabled="disabled"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<button>Reload</button>
```